# Explicit interface implementation related with an IEnumerable<T> implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, ienumerable, explicit-interface

Why in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN example is needed the *GetEnumerator1* method?

```
// Must implement GetEnumerator, which returns a new StreamReaderEnumerator. 
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
{
    return new StreamReaderEnumerator(_filePath);
}

// Must also implement IEnumerable.GetEnumerator, but implement as a private method. 
private IEnumerator GetEnumerator1()
{
    return this.GetEnumerator();
}
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator1();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need, we can just use

```
// Must implement GetEnumerator, which returns a new StreamReaderEnumerator. 

public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
{
    return new StreamReaderEnumerator(_filePath);
}

// Must also implement IEnumerable.GetEnumerator, but implement as a private method. 

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was exactly what I was thinking, but I have a doubt... the `return GetEnumerator();` will not end calling recursively the `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` method?

Comment: @gsc-frank, it won't. To make it recursive you need to cast it to `IEnumerable`: `return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();`